# Why is it ungrammatical to put the preposition at the end of the sentence in "preposition+relative pronoun" sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

> This is my house which I live in.

> This is my house in which I live.

What makes the first ungrammatical here? To me, a non-native speaker, both seem totally fine. Does the first one go against some kind of rhythm of the sentence, or create an unintended confusion?

Comment: Both are fine and correct English grammar, but you could put a comma before "which" and before "in which".  Can you tell us why you think the first sentence is ungrammatical?  Who says that it is wrong?

Comment: Once up on a time, when grammar was ruled by prescriptivists in ivory towers, there was a rule that one must never end a sentence with a preposition. With a few exceptions, nobody anywhere in any variety of English has ever followed this rule. Even our own teachers who beat us over the head with it make the same "mistake" themselves. It's not a rule. Both sentences are correct. The second sounds very formal, even stuffy